# How to open this text file properly in R?

Tags: r

So I have this line of code in a file:

```
{"id":53680,"title":"daytona1-usa"}
```

But when I try to open it in R using this:

```
df <- read.csv("file1.txt", strip.white = TRUE, sep = ":")
```

It produces columns like this:

```
Col1: X53680.title
Col2: daytona1.usa.url
```

What I want to do is open the file so that the columns are like this:

```
Col1: 53680
Col2: daytona1-usa
```

How can I do this in R?

Edit: The actual file I'm reading in is this:

```
{"id":53203,"title":"bbc-moment","url":"https:\/\/wow.bbc.com\/bbc-ids\/live\/enus\/211\/53203","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53204,"title":"shg-moment","url":"https:\/\/wow.shg.com\/shg-ids\/live\/enus\/212\/53204","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53205,"title":"was-zone","url":"https:\/\/wow.was.com\/was-ids\/live\/enus\/213\/53205","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53206,"title":"xx1-zone","url":"https:\/\/wow.xx1.com\/xx1-ids\/live\/enus\/214\/53206","type":"audio\/mpeg"},], WH.ge('zonemusicdiv-zonemusic'), {loop: true});
```

After reading it in, I remove the first column and then every 3rd and 4th column with this:

```
# Delete the first column
df <- df[-1]

# Delete every 3rd and 4th columns
i1 <- rep(seq(3, ncol(df), 4) , each = 2) + 0:1
df <- df[,-i1]
```

Thank you.

Edit 2:

Adding this fixed it:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ".title", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",url", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single JSON in the file, then

```r
jsonlite::read_json("file1.txt")
# $id
# [1] 53680
# $title
# [1] "daytona1-usa"
```

If it is instead NDJSON (`N`ewline-`D`elimited json), then

```r
jsonlite::stream_in(file("file1.txt"), verbose = FALSE)
#      id        title
# 1 53680 daytona1-usa
```

Comment: Could you read the edited part of my question, please?  I added the full file that I'm trying to open but when I try to run your code  to open that file, I see an error Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          /53203","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53204,"title":"shg-momen
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Well that changes things. Portions of it are legal json, but as a whole it is not. I find it odd that the string you show ends its last dict with a following `]` as if it were intended to be a json list of dicts, but there is not an opening `[`. This suggests either that the sample you gave us is incompletely and/or not representative, or the file format is even worse. At this point, there are several ways that parsing it can go, but I'd rather have more of the picture. For instance, is there a leading `[`? Is all of it on one line? Are there any other lists (`[..]`) in the structure?

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers above would have been correct if the data had been formatted properly, it seems they don't work for the data I have so what I ended up going with was this:

```
df <- read.csv("file1.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ":", dec = "-")

# Delete the first column
df <- df[-1]

# Delete every 3rd and 4th columns
i1 <- rep(seq(3, ncol(df), 4) , each = 2) + 0:1
df <- df[,-i1]

df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ".title", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",url", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
```